# DC rating for specific AC rated relay

Tags: ac, relay, dc

I am interested in buying a high amperage relay which is AC rated (https://www.panasonic-electric-works.com/cps/rde/xbcr/pew_eu_en/ds_61A04_en_dqm.pdf). In particular it is rated for 60A @ 240VAC and I would like to use it at a max 12.4VDC circuit. Could you please advice me what is the equivalent amperage rating for DC @ 12.4VDC?
Thanks in advance and I am looking forward to hearing from you.
Best regards
George

Comment: Try asking the manufacturer.

Comment: If there isn't one in the datasheet I would pick another relay. Or failing that, assume something conservative like 10-20A.

Comment: "what is the equivalent amperage rating for DC" - There is no "equivalent DC rating". The permissible DC current is fully dependent on the design of the specific relay and only the manufacturer can tell you if and how much so the relay can handle DC. If no DC rating is provided, go with Brian's comment and take another relay.

Comment: You want to use 12.4VDC as coil voltage (I mean to drive relay) or the 12.4VDC circuit is the circuit you want to break with relay?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the contact current rating is independent of the contact rated voltage.

The application is limited by the contact resistance, and for all types is listed as:

> Contact resistance (Initial) Max. 30 m\$\Omega\$

The maximum current in the contacts is a heating limited function, and therefore the DC capacity will be the same as the RMS capacity.

I would not use this part anywhere close to the rated capacity (calculate \$I^2 R\$ to see why).

[Update with comment from JimmyB]

Who quite rightly states that the *break* current can be much lower for DC than AC, which is another reason to not use this anywhere near the stated rated current.

The test for contact resistance is a DC test:

> (By voltage drop 6 V DC 1A)

so the only current *guaranteed* to be safe is that test current.

Comment: "The application is limited by the contact resistance" - I'd say, it's at least *also* limited by the current the relay can reliably *break*, which can be a *lot* lower for DC than for AC.

Comment: It may be less than this, may not, last relay company I visited did a DC test for contact resistance but were not switching the relay with voltage applied. Relay was powered, current turned on, measured, current turned off, relay un-powered.  So never asked to switch any DC current.

Answer (score 1):

Panasonic are a competent and intelligent manufacturer. Both their components and their documentation are usually both high quality and relatively comprehensive. So ...

If a data sheet for a relay series makes NO mention of DC contact current rating and conditions for a specific relay or relay family then it is extremely likely that they are not intended for use to switch DC. While it would be possible to do so, if Panasonic says "don't" then it's probably a bad idea. Or worse.

Others have suggested that DC current rating of a relay is usually below the AC current rating. While this may be true to some extent, the main limitation for switching DC is usually maximum voltage. Relays that are specified for switching eg 230 VAC often have maximum DC contact voltage of 30 V or less. Higher than this is unusual and much higher is very unusual.

The main limitation in switching DC is the contact set's ability to break the arc that forms at the contact surface. When AC is switched the voltage and current fall to zero and reverse polarity at twice the AC frequency (ie 2 zero crossings per cycle). This drop to 0 Volts and polarity reversal leads to extinguishing of any arc that forms (within the rated operating conditions.) With DC there are no zero crossing points and arcs can form and sustain at far greater distances for a given voltage / current.

It is possible to increase the DC rating of relays using magnetic blowout. Magnetic arrangements are  not complex but very few non integrated solutions of this sort are seen.

Another way to increase maximum DC operating voltage is to place a semiconductor switch (MOSFET or other) across the contacts and to activate it when the contacts open or close. This causes dissipation in the semiconductor switching device only at open/close transitions and allows modestly rated semiconductors to be used.

Answer (score 0):

AC goes through zero many times per second, this assists in breaking the arc that forms when you interrupt a large current.

With DC, the supply is steady, so other methods are needed to break the arc.

This can be by having big heavy (cold) contacts, in combination with a low enough current, which will quench the arc. A high capacity AC relay will have big heavy contacts, which is why derating the current capacity may well be sufficient for DC.

Some relays specifically designed for DC (automobile types for heavy loads) have interesting contact metallurgies, some use magnetic fields in the contact region so that the arc drives itself away from the contacts. An AC relay will not usually have this sort of arc suppressor.

Relays tend to have two ratings, which can be very different, depending on whether the load being broken is pure resistive, or has a significant inductance. An inductive load (motor for instance) will generate a high voltage when the relay attempts to break the current, which will tend to sustain the arc. The inductive breaking capacity will always be lower than the resistive breaking capacity.